# Vue firebase hosting environment variables

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, environment-variables, firebase-hosting

Currently in my dev environment i have my `.env.development` file with my firebase environment variables stored as:

```
VUE_APP_FB_API_KEY='abc123000123',
VUE_APP_FB_AUTH_DOMAIN='site.firebaseapp.com', 
etc...
```

This works fine for my dev machine but once i deploy this to firebase hosting it breaks and throws console errors that the various options are not configured. I tried adding them with

> firebase functions:config:set env.VUE_APP_FB_API_KEY='abc123000123'

but this is still not working for me.

What is wrong here? Also per the docs upper-case characters are not allowed..

Comment: How do you build? Do you have `.env` field (not `.env.development`)?

Comment: @ittus Im using Vue/cli 3 so its built all through vue/webpack

Comment: Rename your `.env.development` file to just `.env` (assuming you use the same Firebase services for dev and prod). See https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables

Comment: @Phil So that worked perfectly! My only question is how is this accomplished if i need separate services for both dev and prod?

Comment: @Phil Yes i did. I had it setup this way before with the separate files and it worked fine in dev and broke in prod, hence the SO question.

Comment: That detail is not in your question. Do the two env files have the same property keys? Ie, the both have `VUE_APP_FB_API_KEY`, `VUE_APP_FB_AUTH_DOMAIN`, etc

Comment: @Phil Sorry, thought i had that in my original post, maybe i fat-fingered something. let me try that again and see if it works.

Answer (score 6):

When you run on local, vue-cli will read `.env.development` config file. But when you build for production, it will use production mode and will read `.env` file.

You should copy `.env.development` to `.env` then build and deploy again.

Or you can create `.env.production` file, which is only used for production build.

> .env                # loaded in all cases
>
> .env.local          # loaded in all cases, ignored by git
>
> .env.[mode]         # only loaded in specified mode
>
> .env.[mode].local   # only loaded in specified mode, ignored by git

You can read more about the enviroment variable and build mode in [vue-cli official document.](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables)